# Is there a way to target an element depending on what is inside it?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

On my page, I have custom styled hyperlinks, and I also have alot of hyperlinked images. I don't want these custom styles to appear on the hyperlinks that only contain images. Instead of adding a separate class (i.e "nostyle") to each hyperlinked image, can I somehow target the hyperlinked images from my stylesheet?

Comment: I wish. +1 to see if someone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot select the parent of a matched item in CSS directly. There are workarounds with js (e.g. Searching elements and applying class attributes to their parent nodes) but seems a bit clumsy. You would rather refactor your document structure to find out a slicker solution.

Comment: Typo alert:  You wrote "clumpsy" rather than "clumsy"

Answer (score 1):

sure, just use

```
a img {
  // your style here...
}
```

if you want to target only the images within a certain class of links, use

```
a.yourclass img {}
```

Comment: This achieves the OP's goal, but doesn't actually do what the title asks.  It targets the image inside a link, but doesn't target the link that happens to contain an image.

Comment: This targets any <img> element that is a descendant of an <a> element. This does not target <a> elements which have an <img> child element.

Comment: well, then I suggest the OP rephrases his question or title. I don't see why my post should be voted down for answering the question.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it is not the correct answer. The correct answer is: you cannot do what the OP is asking. However, the last part of the question is misleading so I un-downvoted.

Comment: I think "I don't want these custom styles to appear on the hyperlinks that only contain images" is clear. His problem is with the links, not with the images.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what it sounds like you're asking for the answer is no.  You can't go backwards in the CSS only forwards.

As Theo.T mentioned, you could have a JS work-around.

One idea is to do an element innerHTML check to see if the element has an <img> tag inside it and if it does, change the element.className = "nostyle"; but that's a messy workaround and by the time you get the syntax right in JS (and cross-browser) you could have re-factored your document.

Answer (score 0):

no need for a anchor class.

```
a[rel="image"] img {}
```

Comment: this requires you to add "rel" attribs to all the necessary links, so you might as well add a class. Attribute selectors don't even work in IE anyway.